# Access store location using product name and country

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a project to show available store location with my product name.

I just received the idea of a client to show store location based on product name, country name and city zip code.

https://prnt.sc/o3elbj

The main idea is described in the link image. User can view store that are offline OR online, using Product name, country name and city zip code.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need suggestions

Comment: What kind of suggestions? What is the difficulty that you're having?

Comment: I just going to start it so I just need an idea to achieve this. Either I have to code myself or I just need a good plugin for this.

Comment: Ok, well that's not really what StackOverflow is for. People expect you to ask a question about something specific that you are stuck with. Not about general suggestions.